# DrRacket 2 list inputs and reversing only one

Tags: scheme, racket

I'll preface this by saying this is for an assignment, but I am not sure how to approach this after going through other stackoverflow questions for an hour or two.

I'm attempting to create a reverse function that accepts 2 lists as input and returns the first list reverse appended with the second list.

Example: `(reverse '(1 2) '(3 4))` --> `(2 1 3 4)`

My code is below, I have tried conditional statements such as when the first list is NOT null then do the main logic, then when it is only return l2 (which still returned `(3 4 2 1)` instead of `(2 1 3 4)`.

The problem I'm having is that no matter what I do the second list is always at the beginning of the first reversed list.

```
(define (myreverse l1 l2)
   (if (null? l) l2)
      (append (myreverse(cdr l1) l2) (list(car l1))))
```

Comment: First, fully reverse the list `l1`. *Then*, use `append` to combine `l1-reversed` with `l2`.

Comment: I think I tried something along the lines of that. ie:
(append (append(rev(cdr l1) l2) (list(car l1))) l2), unless that's not what you mean. Doing that with '(1 2) and '(3 4) outputs (2 3 4 1 3 4).

Comment: What @assefamaru is getting at is that you should decompose this into several functions and not try to do all things at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
(reverse '(1 2 3 4))
=> '(4 3 2 1)

(append (reverse '(1 2)) '(3 4))
=> '(2 1 3 4)
```

Think about how you can implement `reverse`, and how you can use it in your `myreverse` procedure.

Answer (score 0):

With racket/scheme it is very helpful to think of these kinds of problems from the bottom up.

For example, what do you do when the first list is `null?`? Well, you're done! so just return the second list. What do you do when it has just one element? Well, we tack that element onto the second list and we're done. But a moment's thought tells us that all the cases are now covered.

```
(define (rev-first left right)
  (if (null? left)
      right
      (rev-first (??? left) (???? right))))
```

Actually this kind of recursion is captured with `foldl` and `foldr` more generally. But I don't know if it's instructive for you at this point.